# DSPIC33EP AN1307 application note source code

Tags: pic, microchip

I've downloaded source code of an application note from Microchip's web site ([AN1307](https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en546027)). In order to try it, I created a new project in MPLABX. Then I added all source and header files that I've downloaded to the project. When I built the project it gave an error because header file `uart.h` was not included. But there was no `uart.h` file in the source code that I've downloaded from the web site.

What should I do? Where can I find that header file? Should I write it on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uart.h` should be part of your MPLABX installation. According to the makefile it is looking for it in:

```
../../program files/microchip/mplab c30/support/peripheral_30F_24H_33F/UART.h
```

Answer (score 0):

We must have downloaded .exe of related peripheral libraries (PLIBS) from microchips compiler download page. That .exe automatically installs essential files (included uart.h) into the ...\support\peripheral_30F_24H_33F directory.